# How to install xbox silently for deployment on windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, xbox360

My question closed in server fault stating it as off-topic even though it is not.

Could you please at least provide an answer here.

[off-topic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5WxyL.png)

This is for deployment in gaming companies, not home user testing to close it as off-topic.
If it is a home user based, I would have installed with UI itself, won't take any struggle to make it silent.

We want to deploy it through SCCM but not able to install it silently. Please share the steps to install it through SCCM system wide.

Download [link](https://www.xbox.com/en-US/apps/xbox-app-for-pc) for the same.

I tried below commands but none working:

```
XboxAppInstaller.exe /quiet /installLocation "C:\XboxApp"
XboxAppInstaller.exe /quiet
XboxAppInstaller.exe /q
XboxAppInstaller.exe /QUIET
XboxAppInstaller.exe /Quiet
XboxAppInstaller.exe /Q
XboxAppInstaller.exe /S
XboxAppInstaller.exe /s
XboxAppInstaller.exe /silent
XboxAppInstaller.exe /SILENT
XboxAppInstaller.exe /Silent
```

Even I tried copying the folder generated while installing and copying the same on different machine.

```
xcopy /Y c:\users\uday\Desktop\Microsoft.GamingServices_13.78.12002.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.GamingServices_13.78.12002.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe"

Add-AppxPackage -register "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.GamingServices_13.78.12002.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\AppxManifest.xml" -DisableDevelopmentMode
```

But didn't work.

Once it works, please suggest how to install it system wide for all users on the same machine so can deploy using any SCCM.

Comment: Closed questions should be edited not reposted. The application is a UWP application and should be deployed as one. How you deploy a UWP in an enterprise environment isn’t complicated but not straightforward necessarily and it’s well documented. I would need to know where you are stuck in the process, running that executable, isn’t part of that process normally

Comment: it is not documented well in that page. Can you share that if any

Comment: No, since you have no indicated where in the process you are stuck. It’s also been nearly a month since I did my research. Additionally, you posted a closed question, your original question cannot be answered in its current state